# Link between a table row and page

Tags: sql-server, corruption

How can I determine which is the datapage(s) where a row is written on? The opposite, having a datapage, how can I know what kind of data is stored there.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try a partial response. You can see the pages where are stored rows from a specific database:

```
DBCC IND (N'DatabaseName', N'Tablename)
```